# Issues with Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect

Tags: openid-connect, linkedin-api

Being a developer of [keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org) I recently detected that LinkedIn has a product called `Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect` to allow social login with the platform. Trying to configure keycloak to provide a login through LinkedIn openidc I faced two issues:

1. The [jwks endpoint LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/openid/jwks) provides does not provide the `"use":"sig"` field for the signing key. That field is compulsory because OpenID Connect [spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Signing) says *"the key usage of the respective keys MUST support signing"*. Because of that `keycloak` does not allow that key to be used and it should be configured manually.
2. The ID token returned after the code exchange does not contain the nonce submitted at authentication time. This is also something that is required by spec, [point 11 in ID Token Validation](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDTokenValidation). Keycloak sends the nonce and then validates its presence in the ID token, it's dropping the response because the nonce is not there. This point has no workaround right now.

We detected both issues working on the following [keycloak issue](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/22383).

I tried to open a case to LinkedIn as a member and it was closed redirecting me to stackoverflow. So I'm asking here to see if some LinkedIn employee involved in OpenIDC can help or redirect me where to ask about this issue.

I try to use `Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect` and detected two flaws, one has a workaround (but nasty) but the other isn't solvable.

Comment: I’ve also noticed that this implementation doesn’t provide its [discovery endpoint](https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/.well-known/openid-configuration) at the correct location (that being: ISSUER/.well-known/openid-configuration), and the locale returned from the user info endpoint is an object not a string.